# cannot read property myFunction of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, web-applications

I am building a webApp in AngularJS. However, when I am trying to load a particular page, it doesn't load properly and gives the Angular skeleton in the DOM. The Error I get in the console is **cannot read property myFunction of undefined** where my function is

```
     altFind(arr: WeekModel[], hack: number): boolean {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].Hack_id === hack) {
                return true;
            }                
        }
        return false;
    }

    myFunction (hack: number): boolean {
        if (!Array.prototype.find) 
        {
            if (!this.all || this.all.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return this.altFind(this.all, hack);                
        }
        else{
            return this.all.find(ow => hack === ow.Hack_id) != undefined;
        }
    }
```

I seek your help in resolving this issue